# In what encoding is encoding is Spanish "ñ" eñe 0xa4, and the uppercase eñe 0xa5?

Tags: encoding

I'm downloading a file, and in this file the Spanish eñe is

```
<¤> 164, Hex 00a4, Oct 244, Digr Cu
```

I can see this in VIM in

> Jennifer Lilia Pe¤a
>   Marianellys Avenda¤o Noble

Etc, what encoding is this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is Microsoft Codepage 850, also known as DOS 850, or IBM 850.

See also,

- [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)

You can make this UTF-8 with

```
iconv -f CP850 -t UTF8 ./file
```